# Installing Ubuntu without deleting other partitons

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

I have a laptop with windows 7 installed but I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04. My question is that is there a way to install Ubuntu 14.04 without deleting the data on my other partitions like D: drive, E Drive. I understand that i will have to format C: Drive but I don't want to format the rest.


Edit: Thanks for the answers but I was wondering if I could use the partitions for both of the OS as I only have about 10 GB total on my computer. Or alternatively is there a way I could only format the C: Drive with the windows on it and install linux there and then linux caan use the other partitions as well without formatting them. Is this possible Thanks. I want to delete windows but don't want to lose data on other partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Select **something else**
then click on the disk that you want to install ubuntu then change its **mount point to "/" root**. Format that partition with **ext4**. Thats it! **complete the installation**.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to select the manual partitioning method and tell the installer not to format any partition you want to use.

However you'll have to create at least an empty linux(ext3/4) partition where to install Ubuntu (you can choose also to create another empty partition of about 2-3Gigs  as swap). You can re-partition your hard drive, using GParted livecd.

Ubuntu will also install grub2 for you, detecting your other Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete a partition to install ubuntu, you just need a couple empty partitions.  So in your case I would use Windows 7 Disk Management to shrink which ever partition has the most space on it and the result would be you would have unallocated space available.  Then use the Ubuntu installer and select "Something else" as the option on how to install.  And follow these instructions [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) starting under if you have windows heading step 5.  Since you already freed the space using windows.

The only reason I suggest using windows to free the space is because the Ubuntu installer... for me... doesn't always work properly.  But feel free to just goto that link and follow the instructions under heading if you have windows starting from step 1 and skipping what I suggest here.

Answer (score 0):

in windows machine open disk manager,if partition tables shows unlocated space in disk u can use that space for ubuntu installation you can select "something else"option or "setup manual partition" while installing ubuntu.create "/" and "swap"partition (this 2  partition minimum requirement for installing ubuntu)  with unlocated space and proceed for installation.